# Rotman Algebraic Topology Exercise 1.14

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

The question is

> If CX is the cone of X, prove that $X \mapsto CX$ defines a functor $\text{Top} \to \text{Top}$  (the reader must define the behavior on morphisms) (Hint: Use Exercise 1.11)

I did exercise 11, and it says that if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and respects an equivalence relation, i.e. if $X/\sim$, and $Y / \square$ are quotient spaces, $x \sim x'$, then $f(x) \square f(x')$. Then $f$ induces a continuous map $\bar{f}: X / \sim \to Y / \square$.

I see that if $f: X \to Y$, is continuous, then the functor $Tf: TX = CX \to TY = CY$ must be continuous. But I don't see how to do this since we don't know if the original function $f$ respects the equivalence relations.

Comment: Since the relation for forming a cone doesn't depend on anything about the spaces $X$ or $Y$, only the value of the variable on the interval, you are in.

Comment: That is clear now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the confusion comes from what $X$ and $Y$ are in exercise 11 vs the present exercise.  Given a continuous map $f:X\to Y$, you have an induced map $f':X\times I\to Y\times I$ defined by $f'(x,t)=(f(x),t)$, where $I=[0,1]$.  A cone $CX$ is a quotient of $X\times I$ by the relation $(x,1)\sim (x',1)$, for all $x,x'\in X$.  Similarly, $CY$ is $Y\times I$ by $(y,1)\mathbin{\square} (y',1)$, for all $y,y'\in Y$.

Notice that if $(x,t)\sim (x,t')$, then either $(x,t)=(x',t')$ or $t=t'=1$.  The second case is the more interesting one.  Since $f'(x,1)=(f(x),1)$ and $f'(x',1)=(f(x'),1)$, we have that $f'(x,1)\mathbin{\square} f'(x',1)$.  Paired with a similar statement for the first case, by exercise 11 there is an induced map $\overline{f'}:CX\to CY$.  Define $Tf$ to be this $\overline{f'}$.

Comment: Is there a difference between just defining a new function from one already defined and inducing a map? The terminology confuses me a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I left too much unsaid.  It's "induced" from $f$ and $\operatorname{id}_I:I\to I$ in the sense that $f'=f\times \operatorname{id}_I$ using the Cartesian product bifunctor.  I'm using "induced" to mean that it's defined from existing functions in some canonical way, but in the end it's just a function that's defined somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Name the canonical projections by $\pi_1: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ and $\pi_2: Y \rightarrow Y/\square$.

To prove that $\bar{f}$ is continuous, by definition we need to check the preimage of any open sets in $Y/\square$ being open in $X/\sim$.

By the definition of quotient topology, we know **all** open sets $V$ in $Y/\square$ are **exactly** those sets whose preimages in $Y$ are open.

However, $\bar{f}^{-1}(V) = \pi_1(f^{-1}\circ \pi_2^{-1}(V))$, so by definition of the quotient topology of $X/\sim$, $\bar{f}^{-1}(V)$ is open. This proves your statement.

EDIT (for the comment. I am not able to comment before my reputation grows more than 50): from any $f^0: X\rightarrow Y$ you have a naturaly $:XxI \rightarrow YxI$. Then apply my argument above to this $f$.

Comment: Maybe you should be clear that by $X$ and $Y$ you mean $X\times[0,1]$ and $Y\times [0,1]$?

Comment: This was basically what I did for Exercise 1.11, but this doesn't help me define the functor for this exercise, which must map a morphism $f: X \to Y$ to a morphism $\bar{f}: X \times I / \sim \to Y \times I / \square$.